# Python builtin function method exception when using split

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code:

```
value = '20.15-03-03-T:54:12G'
```

And I want to take the first 10 characters

I tried this:

```
newValue = value.split[:9]
```

And I tried this too:

```
newValue = value.split[0:9]
```

In both cases, I got:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I tried to search over internet but it seems that this exception could appear for too many reasons and I didn't find it for the `split` function.

Comment: I think you wanted newValue = value.split()[:9] ... that is to get a slice from the results of calling the .split() method.  value.split evaluates to a function/reference, value.split() calls that function (method) and evaluates into a list resulting from the split.  But, in the context of your code you play need to use re.split() because your value has no spaces nor any other character which would split into 10 components.  string.split() only splits on individual characters (whitespace by default, otherwise single chars).  re.split() can split on regular expressions and character classes.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the [`str.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without calling it:

```
>>> ''.split
<built-in method split of str object at 0x10c7ae848>
```

You cannot slice a method nor do you *want* to split the string on a delimiter. Just slice the string itself, you don't need the `str.split()` method here at all:

```
newValue = value[:9]
```

Note that this gives you the first **nine** characters, not the first 10. Slice to `10` if you wanted the first 10 characters:

```
newValue = value[:10]
```

Demo:

```
>>> value = '20.15-03-03-T:54:12G'
>>> value[:9]
'20.15-03-'
>>> value[:10]
'20.15-03-0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
newValue = value[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slices partition on the interval `[a, b)` meaning that the left endpoint is not included:

```
value[:10] # start at 0 and up to but not including 10, for a total of 10 chars
```

You should also know split is a method, which you can't slice. You have no need for it.